# add calendar in FOSUseBundle's form

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I have some problem. I need add in registration template in FOSUserBundle calendar which allows choose birthday user's - the standard html tag date doesn't fit. To order to do this I used datepicker of jQuery:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#fos_user_registration_form_birthday").datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: '1950:2010',
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            <ol>
             [.........]
                <li>
                    {{ form_label(form.birthday) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.birthday) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.birthday) }}
         
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
                </li>

                    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
                </li>
            </ol>
         [.........]
        </form>
```

It's working fine, but if I override the template and add:

```
{%extends 'MyBlogBundle::layout.html.twig'%}
{% block content %}
  [ form registration]
{% endblock%}
```

It doesn't work.
So, what am I doing wrong?
And I have one more than question - how to add or change class, id in registration form? I tried it in template

```
{{ form_widget(form.birthday {'attr': {'class': 'task_field'}}) }}
```

and in RegistrarionFormType:

```
 ->add('birthday','text',array('attr'=>array('id'=>'text_field')))
```

But id doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm kinda new to this domain but I believe you should include 
    {% block fos_user_content %}
in your main template or overwrite them totaly in your own bundle (your bundle class should then contain getParent() method)

I believe the main template lives in (if your bundle is named UserBundle)

```
UserBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig
```

the most basic overwrite would then be

```
{# UserBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig #}

{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ block('fos_user_content') }}
{% endblock %}


// UserBundle\UserBundle.php
namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return "FOSUserBundle";
    } 

}
```

After that you can copy the templates you want to overload to corresponding bundle folder eg 
    UserBundle\Resources\views\Registration\xx.html.twig
from the FOSUserBundle.

After changing the "include strategy" in your project you must clear your cache also in DEV mode otherwise you wil not see the changes. Changes applied to the content do not need a clearing of your cache.